# Cycle2 Carousel and Bootstrap bug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, cycle2

I have done a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4lUC28p2H5P9BJoOLqvQ) so you can see my problem...

Setting the `col-xs-12` and `col-md-3` (using bootstrap auto-width capabilities) it destroy the cycle2 making the slides get a massive width.

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your question

Comment: I have included a plunkr with the code... The same bug on plunkr is giving on my app...

Comment: Can you copy the relevant parts of the code into the question? The idea is to provide a "minimal working/not working example". The Plunkr looks rather big and complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your slider:

```
data-cycle-carousel-fluid="true"<br>
data-cycle-carousel-visible="X"<br>
```

(X being the amount of visible elements)

Cycle overwrite the width of the element and calculate itself the appropriate one. But the numbers are rounded up so you might need to add a "margin-left:-1px" to the elements in the carousel.